# There is an pending process on Chrome by using vuejs2, but not on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

As below, My vue project always running slowly because of this socketjs process on Chrome, but running normally on Firefox(No socketjs process).
I don't know if it is my config problem?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

SockJS is library for emulating WebSockets. If websockets is found that is used but if not sockJS is used. these requests seem to be [long polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) so taking a long time when nothing has changed is normal behavior.

Is anything in your app actually running slow or are you just concerned about these long running requests?

Comment: Hi, thanks first, these long-time requests affect the smoothness of the page, so much so that I would be slow to click on a route, let alone an HTTP request. I don't know how to close it, and why there is no problem on Firefox?

Comment: I checked with my vue app and I can see the socksJS request on chrome but firefox opens a real websocket. I noticed no performance difference between firefox and chrome. Browsers can handle multiple requests at the same time so this should not be an issue. Another thing to note is socksJS is only used on development and not production (I assume it just reloads the page when you edit the code)

Comment: As you said, maybe my my project running on development environment. I'll check it later after push it on production. Thank you:) .